# Safe Publication of Java object after calling setter on the object

Tags: java, multithreading

Will calling a setter after constructor execution but before returning the reference will be a safe publication ?

```
public class SafePublication {
    private int i = 0;
    private SafePublication() {
            i = 10;
    }

    // Here we are calling setter are object creation. 
    //Will this change be visible to other threads
   public static SafePublication getInstance() {
           SafePublication pub = new SafePublication();
           pub.setVal(20);
           return pub;
   }

   private void setVal(int x) {
           this.i = x;
   }
}
```

Comment: What is unsafe is calling any method and passing a `this` reference from the constructor, as you do not know if it will be used **before** the object has been properly initialized.

Comment: Should the getInstance() method be static?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it won't be safe.

The `setVal` method is not synchronized, and `i` is not volatile.  Therefore, there will be no synchronization point between an update to `i` (via `setVal`) and any code run on another thread that reads `i`.  The fact that the `setVal` call happens in the thread that constructs the instance makes on difference.

The bottom line is that another thread *may* see the value of `i` as any one of `0`, `10` or `20`.

---

> How may another thread see that value if the reference to the object has not been returned yet?

It is not.  The problem is that the other thread *may* not see the correct value of `i`.

I think you are confusing this situation with the case where the field is `final`.  There, the JLS *does* specify that the field is safely published.  The problem is that this guarantee does not apply to non-final fields; see [JLS 17.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5).  The wording is as follows:

> *"An object is considered to be completely initialized when its constructor finishes. A thread that can only see a reference to an object after that object has been completely initialized is guaranteed to see the correctly initialized values **for that object's `final` fields**. "*

(Emphasis added)

---

> i would rather say another thread may see the value of i as any one of 10 or 20. It is guaranteed not to see 0.

AFAIK, there is nothing in [JLS 17.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4) or [JLS 17.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.5) that offers that guarantee.  The only thing that is guaranteed is that nothing will see the value of `i` before default initialization has taken place.  (Please feel free to prove me wrong ... with references to the JLS.)

Comment: How may another thread see that value if the reference to the object has not been returned yet?

Comment: SJuan76 .. even if the reference is returned, it is still possible that other thread see stale data because i is not synchronized.

Comment: i would rather say another thread may see the value of i as any one of  10 or 20. It is guaranteed not to see 0.

Comment: No, after `pub.setValue(20);`, all threads see the current data. But still only one thread has access to the object until it is returned by `getInstance()`

Comment: I think you just over looked the constructor. Safe construction is guaranteed and there itself it is getting initialized to value 10. So it another thread won't see value 0.

Comment: @user1942587 - please provide us with a JLS reference / quotation to support that assertion.  I can't find one.

Comment: "An object is considered to be completely initialized when its constructor finishes. "

In this initialization itself .. it is saying .. i is guaranteed to be set to 10 after the constructor finishes.

Comment: @StephenC please see my comments.

Comment: @GauravSingh - So how do you explain the sentence after that which **ONLY** says that another thread guaranteed to see the correct initial values for `final` fields?  Your argument is unconvincing ... when you compare it to the precise language of 17.4, and when you consider that it is in the context of the description of the semantics of `final` fields.

Comment: @StephenC will put in a reference from java concurrency in practice. G

Comment: @GauravSingh - JCiP is a secondary source.  If what you are asserting is true, then it *will* be specified in the JLS.  The fact that you cannot find it there (and I can't) says to me that your assertion is without a proper foundation.

Comment: @StephenC Haven't gone through JLS. However, would like to sight my references and understanding from JCIP. 
We can publish a properly constructed object ( in our case we are constructing it properly see Sec 3.2.1 Safe Construction Practices JCIP) following the Safe Publication idiom Sc 3.5.3 in JCIP.

Comment: @StephenC 
My Point we we are safely constructing it but not safely publishing it because we called setter before publishing. 

So I agree to your point that there is no synchronizing point between constructor call and setVal method call. 

However, i = 10 is synchronized as it was assigned in a safely constructed SafePublication Object. 

So other thread will see 10 or 20 but never 0.

Comment: @GauravSingh - Actually, the problem is that you are NOT following the requirements of JCIP 3.5.3 for safe publication.  Specifically, you are doing NONE of the 4 things listed that would guarantee safe publication.

Comment: @StephenC Agreed I am not doing none of the 4 thing discussed in JCIP. That is why I am skeptical about if the object will be published safely or not. Second, I am constructing the object safely ( not publishing partially initialized object ) so i must be atleast 10 in any of the threads accessing it.

Comment: See there is a difference in constructing and publishing. We are constructing properly but safe publication idiom is not met because we called setter on the object.

Comment: @StephenC been going through Java Memory Model for last few days. You were very correct. Other thread can see i as 0, 10, 20. 
I thought constructor ensures safe publication of its state variables after finishing execution. I wrong there. It will only ensure safe publication for final fields. Please comment if I am mistaken.

Comment: @GauravSingh - your latest comment is correct.  Nothing more to say :-)